# subset column names from df to plot specific coefficients from regression R

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to plot only a select few coefficients from a regression, but my regression has 100s of variables, so I'm trying to think of a way to extract the coefficients using better coding.

I have this regression below:

```
n <- 1e3
d <- data.frame(
  # Covariates
  x1 = rnorm(n),
  x2 = rnorm(n),
  x3 = rnorm(n),
  x4 = rnorm(n),
  # Individuals and firms
  id = factor(sample(20, n, replace=TRUE)),
  firm = factor(sample(13, n, replace=TRUE)),
  # Noise
  u = rnorm(n)
)

id.eff <- rnorm(nlevels(d$id))
firm.eff <- rnorm(nlevels(d$firm))

d$y <- d$x1 + 0.5*d$x2 + id.eff[d$id] + firm.eff[d$firm] + d$u

est <- felm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 | id + firm, data = d)
```

But I only want to plot x1 & x2, so I extract the column names I want:

```
d_names = names(d)
N <- -4
d_cleaned_names <- head(d_names, -N)

d_cleaned_names_filter <- d_cleaned_names[1:2]
```

I then add quotation marks and paste it into one continuous character:

```
d_cleaned_names_filter_quote <- shQuote(d_cleaned_names_filter)
d_cleaned_filter_quote_names = paste(d_cleaned_names_filter_quote, collapse =  ',' )
```

and when I plot this:

```
jtools::plot_coefs(est,plot.distributions = TRUE, inner_ci_level = .9, coefs = c(d_cleaned_names_filter_quote))
```

I get the error:

```
Error in if (rescale.distributions == FALSE && max(heights)/min(heights) >  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In max(heights) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In min(heights) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

but this works perfectly writing 'x1' & 'x2' out manually. However, this is not that feasible for a large dataset:

```
jtools::plot_coefs(est,plot.distributions = TRUE, inner_ci_level = .9, coefs = c('x1', 'x2'))
```

Any advice would be very welcome.

Comment: can't you use `coefs=d_cleaned_names_filter`  directly in the `plot_coef` function?

Comment: ouch -- apparently you can? not sure why i didn't try it earlier :/ thanks!